# Flex - image constraints

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following thumbnail code, which I have built for my image thumbnails.

The idea is that the `.dummy` pads the area into a square, with `.image` being the canvas at this square size. `.image` is the parent flex container, with `.hug` the flex child. `.hug` is there to 'hug' the image, so I can apply the `.shadow` class just the size of the image.

The problem is, the containers all work correctly, but the image does not stay contained within the container centered vertically and horizontally proportionally.

```css
.thumbnail-item {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #EEE;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}

.thumbnail-item .dummy {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.thumbnail-item .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.thumbnail-item .image .hug {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.thumbnail-item .image .hug img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.shadow {
  position: relative;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #777;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  &:after {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-item">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="hug shadow">
      <img src="https://news.dphotographer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/RS35514_Lead-Image-new.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to understand why the image isn't staying within its container? and how its possible to amend my code so it does?

Answer (score 0):

Please give this css to `img` tag

```
.thumbnail-item .image .hug img {height: auto;max-height: 100%;max-width: 100%;width: auto;}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I have applied this to my example above, but it does not solve the 'height' issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your image does not respect parent size because your parent (`.hug`) does not have an actual size. `max-height` and `max-width` will restrict size of an element but it does not **set** the size for this element. So you need to set the size for your `.hug` by adding `width: 100%; height: 100%`

```css
.thumbnail-item {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #EEE;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}

.thumbnail-item .dummy {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.thumbnail-item .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.thumbnail-item .image .hug {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.thumbnail-item .image .hug img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px #123;
}

.shadow {
  position: relative;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #777;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  &:after {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-item">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="hug shadow">
      <img src="https://news.dphotographer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/RS35514_Lead-Image-new.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this then defeats the point of the '.hug' div. I need this to wrap tight around the image size and then sit centrally within '.image'. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Hmm... It is so hard. Why do you want the `.hug` *hug* your image? To create a shadow?

Comment: Yes, I need it to hug the image to apply the shadow to just the width of the image.

Comment: So, why don't you add `box-shadow` directly for the `img`? See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

**Updated**

I have changed some code -

```
.thumbnail-item {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #EEE;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.thumbnail-item .image .hug {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.thumbnail-item .image .hug img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.thumbnail-item {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #EEE;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.thumbnail-item .dummy {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.thumbnail-item .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.thumbnail-item .image .hug {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%)
}

.thumbnail-item .image .hug img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.shadow {
  position: relative;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #777;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  &:after {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-item">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="hug shadow">
      <img src="https://news.dphotographer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/RS35514_Lead-Image-new.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check if it helps you. :)

Comment: Thank you, but I need the image to be proportional and center within this square canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `object-fit` CSS property that will specifies how your content(image) fitted to the box established by using height and width set to max.

```css
.thumbnail-item {
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #EEE;
  padding-top: 50px;
  max-height: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.thumbnail-item .dummy {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.thumbnail-item .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.thumbnail-item .image .hug {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%)
}

.thumbnail-item .image .hug img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.shadow {
  position: relative;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #777;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  &:after {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-item">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="hug shadow">
      <img src="https://news.dphotographer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/RS35514_Lead-Image-new.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will solve your question!